# Mininet: Pingall 100% Dropped

Tags: mininet

I cannot receive any packets when I pingall in mininet custom topology. I want to create a mininet network with the following configuration:

[image: Network]

My custom topology looks like this:

```
class NetworkTopo(Topo):
    def build(self, **_opts):
        
        r1 = self.addHost("r1", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.101.0.1/24")
        r2 = self.addHost("r2", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.102.0.1/24")
        r3 = self.addHost("r3", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.103.0.1/24")
        r4 = self.addHost("r4", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.104.0.1/24")
        r5 = self.addHost("r5", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.105.0.1/24")
        r6 = self.addHost("r6", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.106.0.1/24")
        r7 = self.addHost("r7", cls=LinuxRouter, ip="10.107.0.1/24")

        self.addLink(
            r1,
            r2,
            intfName1="r1-eth1",
            intftName2="r2-eth1",
            params1={"ip": "10.108.0.1/24", "bw": 900},
            params2={"ip": "10.108.0.2/24", "bw": 900},
        )

        self.addLink(
            r1,
            r5,
            intfName1="r1-eth2",
            intftName2="r5-eth1",
            params1={"ip": "10.109.0.1/24", "bw": 700},
            params2={"ip": "10.109.0.2/24", "bw": 700},
        )

        self.addLink(
            r1,
            r7,
            intfName1="r1-eth3",
            intftName2="r7-eth1",
            params1={"ip": "10.110.0.1/24", "bw": 200},
            params2={"ip": "10.110.0.2/24", "bw": 200},
        )

        self.addLink(
            r2,
            r3,
            intfName1="r2-eth2",
            intftName2="r3-eth1",
            params1={"ip": "10.111.0.1/24", "bw": 300},
            params2={"ip": "10.111.0.2/24", "bw": 300},
        )
```

The rest of the links are according to the diagram, but I couldn't add them due to too much code in the question.

The run command takes in the following:

```
def run():
    topo = NetworkTopo()
    net = Mininet(
        topo=topo,
        controller=lambda name: RemoteController(name, ip="127.0.0.1"),
        switch=OVSBridge,
        autoSetMacs=True,
    )

    net.start()
    print("Dumping the Node Information")
    dumpNodeConnections(net.hosts)
    print("Testing the network connectivity")
    net.pingAll()
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()
```

When I run my custom topology in Python, I get all packets dropped when performing pingall:

[image: Error]

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.